# $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + (n-1)^2 \equiv 0$ mod n iff $n \equiv \pm 1$ mod 6

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The problem is as follows: Prove that $$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + (n-1)^2 \equiv 0 \, \text{mod n} \ \text{if and only if } n \equiv \pm 1 \, \text{mod} 6.$$

My idea is to of course rewrite the summation. We have $$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + (n-1)^2 = \frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6}.$$

Now, in order for this to be an integer, must we have in particular that $6 \mid n-1 \Rightarrow n \equiv 1 \, \text{mod} 6$?

We also know that the sum $$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \ldots + (n-1)^2 + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$ Must we have in particular that then $6 \mid n+1 \Rightarrow n \equiv -1 \, \text{mod} 6$?

I think the statement holds if and only if the whole way so we are done with both ways?

Comment: $$\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}6$$ is always an integer!

Comment: There is no need to check if the right hand side is an integer. You're guaranteed that it is an integer because of the equality with the left hand side (though you can check cases to make it clear for yourself).

Comment: Yes, it is always an integer, but how do I get to the conclusion that $6 \mid n-1$ and $6 \mid n+1$ from this then? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the proof, we use the following observations:

(i) Suppose that $n$ divides $\frac{(n-1)(n)(2n-1)}{6}$. Then 
$6n$ divides $(n-1)(n)(2n-1)$, and therefore $6$ divides $(n-1)(2n-1)$.

(ii) Conversely, if $6$ divides $(n-1)(2n-1)$, then $6n$ divides $(n-1)(n)(2n-1)$, and therefore  $n$ divides $\frac{(n-1)(n)(2n-1)}{6}$.

---

We first show that if $\gcd(n,6)\gt 1$, then $6$ cannot divide $(n-1)(2n-1)$.
This is obvious if $n$ is even, since then $n-1$ and $2n-1$ are odd. So suppose that $3$ divides $n$.  Then $3$ cannot divide $n-1$ or $2n-1$.

We have shown that if $1^2+2^2+\cdots+(n-1)^2$ is divisible by $n$, then $n$ and $6$ must be relatively prime, and therefore $n\equiv \pm 1\pmod{6}$.

---

Next we show that if $n\equiv \pm 1\pmod{6}$, then $6$ divides $(n-1)(2n-1)$. This is obvious if $n\equiv 1\pmod{6}$.

If $n\equiv -1\pmod{6}$, then $2n\equiv -2\pmod{6}$, and therefore $2n-1\equiv -3\pmod{6}$, and therefore $3$ divides $2n-1$. Moreover, $n$ is odd, so $n-1$ is even, and therefore $6$ divides $(n-1)(2n-1)$.

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $6 \mid (n-1)(2n-1)$ implies that $n$ is odd and cannot be divisible by $3$.

Comment: Why can it not be divisible by 3?

Comment: If $3\mid n$ then $3\not\mid n-1$ and $3\not\mid2n-1$. Hence $3\not\mid (n-1)(2n-1)$.

Comment: How does that get me closer to the conclusion though? :)

Comment: Any odd number is $6k\pm1$ or $6k+3$. The second case is not possible, since $3 \mid 6k+3$.

Answer (score 1):

$n\mid\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}k^2\iff n|\frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(2n-1)}{6}\iff 6|(n-1)\cdot(2n-1)$

Let us prove that $6|(n-1)\cdot(2n-1)\implies n\equiv\pm1\pmod6$.

if $ n\equiv 1\pmod 6$, we have the desired result.

Let us consider the case when $n\not\equiv 1 \pmod 6$. We will show $n\equiv -1 \pmod 6$

Since $(2n-1)$ is odd and $6(=2\cdot 3)\not\mid(n-1)\implies 2\mid(n-1)\implies n\equiv 1\equiv -1\pmod{2}$

Since $(2n-1)$ is odd and $6(=2\cdot 3)\not\mid(n-1)\implies 3\mid(2n-1)\implies 2n\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$

$\implies n\equiv 2^{-1}\equiv 2\equiv-1\pmod{3}$

i.e., $n\equiv-1\pmod 2 \,\&\, n\equiv -1\pmod 3\implies n\equiv -1 \pmod 6$ using property of congruences or by using Chinese Remainder Theorem.

For the other way consider $n\equiv\pm1\pmod6$.

$n\equiv1\pmod6\implies 6\mid(n-1)$.

$n\equiv-1\pmod6\implies n\equiv 5 \pmod6\implies n\equiv1\pmod2\&\,n\equiv2\pmod3$.

$\implies n\equiv 1\pmod 2 \&\, 2n\equiv 1 \pmod3\implies 2\mid (n-1)\&\,3\mid(2n-1)$

$\implies 6\mid(n-1)\cdot(2n-1)$